# how can I check which submit button was pressed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a two submit buttons set up for form submission.
 I'd like to know which submit button was clicked without applying a .click() event to each one.
One more thing I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and want to get the clicked button name in Controller.

Here's the setup:

```
<a class="anchorbutton">
  <input  type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" class="hrbutton"/>
</a>
<input  type="submit" value="Save & Next" id="SaveNext" class="hrbutton  anchorbutton"/>           


 $('#form').live('submit', function (e)    
{      
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#form');      
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#div").html(data);                     

                }
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Post(FormCollection form, string submitButton)
{         

}
```

Comment: which jquery version you are using

Comment: i am using Jquery 1.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well try  binding the click event handler to the Save and SaveAndNext buttons like

```
$(document).delegate("#Save,#SaveAndNext","click",function(e){
 console.log($(this).attr("id"));//here you will know which button was pressed
 //next you can check if the form is valid or not
 if($(this).closest('form').valid()){
 //form is valid submit it ajax(ily)

 }else{
 //form is not valid
 }
});
```

you can also cache the selector

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your buttons names:

```
<a class="anchorbutton">
    <button type="submit" name="save" id="Save" class="hrbutton">Save</button>
</a>
<button type="submit" name="savenext" id="SaveNext" class="hrbutton anchorbutton">Save & Next</button>
```

and then your controller action could take those parameters with the same name and check if it has a value:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(string save, string saveNext, FormCollection form)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(save))
    {
        // The Save button was clicked
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveNext))
    {
        // The Save & Next button was clicked
    }
    else
    {
        // None of the submit buttons were used or clicked to submit the form.
        // The user simply pressed the Enter key while the focus was inside
        // some of the input fields of the form
    }

    ...
}
```

Oh and by the way, the `.live` jQuery function is deprecated. Use `.on` instead.

Comment: $("#form").submit(function (event)    
    {});  i got the button name in Controller but validation not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    ButtonClick Event " OnClick="MyButton_Click" "
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i mention in question i dn't want to use click event.